How to manage install the old libraries on react.js 19 and next.js 15
How you manage the state in nextjs 15 and reactjs 19!?
I can't use any package or it gives me an error when I try to install it.
I've been trying to install

Redux toolkit
Zustand
jotai

so please help if you can solve it, this is the error:


npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: jotai@2.10.3
npm ERR! Found: react@19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0 || 19.0.0-rc-66855b96-20241106" from next@15.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/next
npm ERR!     peer next@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0 || ^12.0.0 || ^13.0.0 || ^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from next-intl@3.25.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/next-intl
npm ERR!       next-intl@"^3.25.3" from the root project
npm ERR!     next@"15.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0 || >=19.0.0-rc <19.0.0" from next-intl@3.25.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/next-intl
npm ERR!     next-intl@"^3.25.3" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (react-dom, styled-jsx, use-intl, the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional react@">=17.0.0" from jotai@2.10.3
npm ERR! node_modules/jotai
npm ERR!   jotai@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.3.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peerOptional react@">=17.0.0" from jotai@2.10.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/jotai
npm ERR!     jotai@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\mrsni\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-27T17_48_09_411Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\mrsni\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-11-27T17_48_09_411Z-debug-0.log




Please focus on one question. Either ask how to manage the state or how to fix the error.

You can manage the state in React JS by using the React's state management features or integrating with a state management library:
React's state management features: Use the useState and useEffect hooks to manage the local state within a page.
State management libraries: Integrate with a state management library like:
Avoid using a global store. Since App Router can handle multiple requests simultaneously, using a global store could lead to data being handled from two different requests simultaneously.

Thanks, but I want to make state that will manage the main layout of my dashboard so it will be needed through the components, so in your opinion how should I manage it?

You can use a react context provider in Next.js, to manage the state of data provided to the client. reference - https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#using-context-providers
